# node js:add mysql query result to json in forloop

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I am trying to add query result from in for loop to JSON

```
function (req,res){
var result  = [{id:1
},{id:2},{id:3}];

for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                        //query run
                       collection.getImages(result[i].id,function (status,error,image) {
                          //add query result to json
                          result[i]['images']=image;

                       });
                   }

 res.json(result);

}
```

But the final `result` doesn't contains the newly added key value(ie `images`) it because `collection.getImages()` is asynchronous so how can i
solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to handle your asynchronous calls. Then you can use `Promise.all()` to await all actions before sending your result back to the client.

```
var result = [
    {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}
];

var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    //query run
    promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        collection.getImages(result[i].id, function (status, error, image) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(image);
            }
        });
    }));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function (images) {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        result[i]['image'] = images[i];
    }
    res.json(result)
}).catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
});
```

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'images' of undefined`